# C++ Array containing base/derived class objects

Tags: c++, arrays

I'm trying to put together an assignment here and got stuck on one point. The question is to create Person class with Student derived class. Then overload both << and >> operators. In the end create checking program to create array of 20 Persons and keep loading either Person or Student. At any point we can print what we have by far - Person output is `Name char*`/`Age int`/`Parents *char[2]`, Student output is `Name char*`/`Age int`/`ID int`.

My problem is with the array point - I can't figure out how to implement this and right now I'm stuck with:

- Array of pointers to person
- We choose if its person/student
- istream to get the data

Here is main code part:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
#include "Header.h"
using namespace std;
int main()

{
    char choice;
    Person* Tablica[20];
    Person* temp;
    int i = 0;
    while (1)
    {
        cout << "choices:" << endl;
        cout << "(p)erson, (s)tudent, s(h)ow, (e)nd" << endl;
        choice = _getch();
        if (choice == 'h' || choice == 'H'){
            for (int n = 0; n < i; n++){
                cout << *Tablica[n] << endl;
            }
        }
        if (choice == 'e' || choice == 'E'){ break; }
        if (choice == 'p' || choice == 'P'){
            temp = new Person;
            cin >> *temp;
            Tablica[i] = temp;
            cout << *Tablica[i] << endl;
            i++;
        }
        if (choice == 'S' || choice == 's'){
            temp = new Student;
            cin >> *temp;
            Tablica[i] = temp;
            cout << *Tablica[i] << endl;
            i++;
        }
    }
    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

I'm able to load first person/student and then code breaks without error.
So what I'm asking here is, could you look at the code and perhaps point me in the right direction?

Disclaimer: We have to use array, no vectors etc. Yes, conio.h is there as well and it has to stay... Obviously I'm beginner.

Person:

```
#include <iostream>

class Person
{
public:
    Person();
    Person(const Person&);
    Person(char* n, int a, char* Parent1, char* Parent2);
    char* getName();
    int getAge();
    char* getDad();
    char* getMum();
    virtual ~Person();
    virtual Person operator=(const Person &);
    virtual Person operator+(const Person &);
    virtual Person operator+=(Person &);
    virtual void write(std::ostream&);
    virtual void read(std::istream&);
    friend std::istream& operator>>(std::istream&, Person &);
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, Person &);
protected:
    char* name;
    int age;
    char* ParentName[2];
};

class Student : public Person
{
public:
    Student();
    Student(const Student&);
    Student(char* name, int age, int id);
    virtual ~Student();
    int ident();
    Student operator=(const Student &);
    Student operator+(const Student &);
    Student operator+=(Student &);
    virtual void write(std::ostream&);
    virtual void read(std::istream&);
    friend std::istream& operator>>(std::istream&, Student &);
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, Student &);
private:
    int ID;
};
```

Class

```
#include "Header.h"

Person::Person(){
    name = 0;
    age = 0;
    ParentName[0] = 0;
    ParentName[1] = 0;
}
Person::Person(const Person & other)
{
    name = other.name;
    age = other.age;
    ParentName[0] = other.ParentName[0];
    ParentName[1] = other.ParentName[1];
}

Person::Person(char* n, int a, char* Parent1, char* Parent2){
    name = n;
    age = a;
    ParentName[0] = Parent1;
    ParentName[1] = Parent2;
}

Person::~Person(){}

char* Person::getName(){ return name; }
int Person::getAge(){ return age; }
char* Person::getDad(){ return ParentName[0]; }
char* Person::getMum(){ return ParentName[1]; }

Person Person::operator=(const Person & other){
    name = other.name;
    age = other.age;
    ParentName[0] = other.ParentName[0];
    ParentName[1] = other.ParentName[1];
    return *this;
}

Person Person::operator+=(Person & other){
    int i;
    i = strlen(name) + strlen(other.name) + 4;
    char * temp = new char[i];
    strcpy_s(temp, i, name);
    strcat_s(temp, i, " - ");
    strcat_s(temp, i, other.name);
    name = temp;
    Person wynik(name, age, ParentName[0], ParentName[1]);
    return wynik;
}

Person Person::operator+(const Person & other){
    int i;
    i = strlen(name) + strlen(other.name) + 4;
    char * temp = new char[i];
    strcpy_s(temp, i, name);
    strcat_s(temp, i, " - ");
    strcat_s(temp, i, other.name);
    Person wynik(temp, age, ParentName[0], ParentName[1]);
    return *this;
}

void Person::write(std::ostream& os)
{
    os << "Osoba: name = " << this->getName() << ", wiek = " << this->getAge() << ", rodzice: " << this->getDad() << ", " << this->getMum();
}

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, Person & other){
    other.write(os);
    return os;
}

void Person::read(std::istream& is)
{
    char* name;
    name = new char;
    std::cout << "name: " << std::endl;
    is >> name;
    std::cout << "age: " << std::endl;
    int age;
    is >> age;
    std::cout << "dad: " << std::endl;
    char* dad;
    dad = new char;
    is >> dad;
    std::cout << "mum: " << std::endl;
    char* mum;
    mum = new char;
    is >> mum;
    Person p(name, age, dad, mum);
    *this = p;
}

std::istream & operator>>(std::istream & is, Person & os){
    os.read(is);
    return is;
}

Student::Student() : Person(){}

Student::Student(const Student& student) : Person(student){
    ID = student.ID;
}

Student::Student(char* name, int age, int id) : Person(name, age, 0, 0){
    ID = id;
}

Student::~Student(){}

Student Student::operator=(const Student & student){
    Person::operator=(static_cast<Person const&>(student));
    ID = student.ID;
    return *this;
}

Student Student::operator+=(Student & student){
    Student wynik(*this);
    wynik.Person::operator=(wynik.Person::operator+=(student));
    return wynik;
}

Student Student::operator+(const Student& student)
{
    Person::operator+(static_cast<Person const&>(student));
    return *this;
}

void Student::write(std::ostream& os)
{
    os << "Student: name = " << this->getName() << ", age = " << this->getAge() << ", legitymacja: " << this->ident() << std::endl;
}

int Student::ident(){ return ID; }

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, Student & other){
    other.write(os);
    return os;
}

void Student::read(std::istream& is)
{
    char* name;
    name = new char[20];
    std::cout << "name: " << std::endl;
    is >> name;
    std::cout << "age: " << std::endl;
    int age;
    is >> age;
    std::cout << "ID: " << std::endl;
    int id;
    is >> id;
    Student s(name, age, id);
    *this = s;
}


std::istream & operator>>(std::istream & is, Student & st){
    st.read(is);
    return is;
}
```

Comment: Awwwww, there are so many question about this topic and why it's flawed :P ...

Comment: `We have to use array, no vectors etc`  We have to use vacuum tubes, no transistors...

Comment: You need to provide more information, most notably the implementations of `>>`.

Comment: This code won’t even compile. Please post the **actual** code.

Comment: Osoba::read piling up data in a zero-length C-string. Your heap must love you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this compile?

```
Table[i] = *temp;
```

`Table` is an array of pointers to `Person`

`temp` is a pointer to `Person`

You are trying to put an *object* into an array that holds *pointers*.  Dereferencing `*temp` gives you an object - you need a pointer to an object, so don't dereference it there.  I would expect the compiler to complain about that... does it?

Also, check your second `if` statement - it says `(choice == 'S' || choice == 'p')`, which is probably not what you meant.  Both `if` blocks will execute if choice == 'p'...

And in `Person::read()` you've only allocated a single character for name.  That is likely to end badly...